# Adding a Column Containing Groupby and Count Arguments Into a Dataframe Using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, group-by, count

I need to add a column into a dataframe containing the count of rows grouped by three other column.

The table at hand looks like this

```
 Index   Col0    Col1    Col2    Col3

  01      a1     '1'     '2'    '1'
  02      a2     '1'     '2'    '2'
  02      a3     '1'     '2'    '2'
  04      a4     '1'     '2'    '2'
  05      a5     '1'     '2'    '2'
  06      a6     '2'     '2'    '2'
```

I need to group by Col1, Col2, and Col3, then count. The desired results should look like this:

```
Index   Col0    Col1    Col2    Col3   Col4
 01      a1     '1'     '2'    '1'     1
 02      a2     '1'     '2'    '2'     4
 02      a3     '1'     '2'    '2'     4
 04      a4     '1'     '2'    '2'     4
 05      a5     '1'     '2'    '2'     4
 06      a6     '2'     '2'    '2'     1
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I am not understanding the formula behind `col4`, can you help me understand ?

Comment: Are the numbers strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df['col4']=df.groupby(['Col1','Col2','Col3']).transform('count').values[:,0]
```

I think you had a typo in your desired output, if you want logic on it, it has to be:

```
   Index Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  col4
0      1   a1     1     2     1     1
1      2   a2     1     2     2     4
2      2   a3     1     2     2     4
3      4   a4     1     2     2     4
4      5   a5     1     2     2     4
5      6   a6     2     2     2     1
```

Comment: Works great, thanks mate. I totally forgot about listing values.

Comment: @AbdulazizAl-Mojil Happy to help, :-)